# google sheets search column for value using python

Tags: python-3.x, google-sheets

I can search a whole table in google sheets with python using the code below.

```
cell = sheet.find("searchCriteria")
```

or

```
cell = sheet.findall("searchCriteria")
```

My question is,  How do I search a specific column in a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to search with the specific column.
- You want to achieve this using gspread with python.

  - From your script, I thought that you might use gspread.

For this, how about this modification? In this case, please use `in_column` as the argument.

#### Modified script:

When the value is searched from the column "C", please modify as follows. [Ref](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/blob/master/gspread/models.py#L1745)

```
cell = sheet.find("searchCriteria", in_column=3)
```

and

```
cell = sheet.findall("searchCriteria", in_column=3)
```

#### Note:

- **When you test this, please update gspread to the latest version. Please be careful this.**

#### References:

- [find(query, in_row=None, in_column=None)](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=find#gspread.models.Worksheet.find)
- [findall(query, in_row=None, in_column=None)](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=find#gspread.models.Worksheet.findall)

Comment: @BigEfromDaBX Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.